# How to remove column row values ​from table according to another column with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a question related to a dynamically mounted table.

So I wanted to know how I can edit the table removing values ​​from rows according to values ​​from another column with jquery? For example, I have the following table:

| Start | End | balance | Trail | Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/11/2022 | 01/15/2022 | 4 | high stretch | 2 |
| 01/11/2022 | 01/15/2022 | 4 | low stretch | 2 |
| 01/25/2022 | 01/30/2022 | 6 | high stretch | 4 |
| 01/25/2022 | 01/30/2022 | 6 | inert stretch | 4 |
| 01/25/2022 | 01/30/2022 | 6 | low stretch | 4 |

Given this table, I wanted to do a merge based on the Id column, removing the balance values, as they are repeated for the same Id and in the end make the sum, returning the balance total.

So the new table would look like this:

| Start | End | balance | Trail | Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/11/2022 | 01/15/2022 | 4 | high stretch | 2 |
| 01/11/2022 | 01/15/2022 |  | low stretch | 2 |
| 01/25/2022 | 01/30/2022 | 6 | high stretch | 4 |
| 01/25/2022 | 01/30/2022 |  | inert stretch | 4 |
| 01/25/2022 | 01/30/2022 |  | low stretch | 4 |
| Total |  | 10 |  |  |

Any idea how I can do this with jquery?

An important detail, this table is dynamically generated, so I can have more rows being generated with other values ​​from other Ids or the same Id.

Comment: Kindly add what you've done so far so we can help better.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sumBalance(){
  var table = document.getElementById("balanceTbl");
  var tbody = table.tBodies[0];
  var tr = table.tBodies[0].rows;
  var totalBal = 0;
  for(i=0; i < tr.length;i++){
    var balance = tbody.rows[i].cells[2].children[0].value;
    totalBal += Number(balance);
  }
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = totalBal;
}
sumBalance();

document.querySelectorAll("input[name=balance]").forEach(function(balanceElem,pos){
  balanceElem.addEventListener("input",function(){
    sumBalance();
  })
})
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table id="balanceTbl">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Start</th>
<th>End</th>
<th>balance</th>
<th>Trail</th>
<th>Id</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>01/11/2022</td>
<td>01/15/2022</td>
<td><input type="text" name="balance" value="4" size="2"></td>
<td>high stretch</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>01/11/2022</td>
<td>01/15/2022</td>
<td><input type="text" name="balance" value="4" size="2"></td>
<td>low stretch</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>01/25/2022</td>
<td>01/30/2022</td>
<td><input type="text" name="balance" value="6" size="2"></td>
<td>high stretch</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>01/25/2022</td>
<td>01/30/2022</td>
<td><input type="text" name="balance" value="6" size="2"></td>
<td>inert stretch</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>01/25/2022</td>
<td>01/30/2022</td>
<td><input type="text" name="balance" value="6" size="2"></td>
<td>low stretch</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<td>Total</td>
<td></td>
<td id="total"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Don't use id, because in HTML id should be unique between each element, Instead of ID use either name or class. Try to change the balance and see the total. Hope this sample will help. Thanks